# Rendered Size of Printed Page using CSS @Page

Tags: c#, css, pdf-generation, css-paged-media

Hi and thanks for looking!

### Background

I am printing a multi-page report using [Rotativa PDF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335595/Rotativa-how-to-print-PDF-in-Asp-Net-MVC) which prints pages of HTML to a PDF.  In doing this, I need to follow @page conventions of CSS 2.1 and higher.

My application is in C#, MVC 3.

### Problem/Question:

Even if I specify 8.5in by 11in in the @page declaration, the page within the printed PDF is only scaled to about 75% of the 8.5X11 sheet.  I know this because I have a background image that should cover the entire page, but it prints to the PDF at only about 75% of the whole page.  The content is scaled down too so everything is proportionally correct, just not canvasing the whole 8.5X11 frame as it should.

I am setting up the cover page of the report like this in CSS:

```
@page defaultPage{size:8.5in 11in;margin: 2cm;}    
#CoverPage {
        page: defaultPage;
        background-image: url(/Resources/rendered_assets/img/cover_bg.jpg); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:8.5in;
        height: 11in;           
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
 <div id="CoverPage">
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>bar</p>
 </div>
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other (hidden) images or elements which account for the 25% other percent on your HTML page (such as a transparent image which is *that* wide somewhere in the header or footer?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know if it would solve your problem.. but with the latest [Rotativa](http://nuget.org/packages/Rotativa) release you get the possibility to pass some options to the rendering engine. You can set PageWidth and PageHeight and Margins like this:

```
    return new ViewAsPdf()
    {
        FileName = "TestView.pdf",
        PageSize = Size.A3,
        PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 }, // it's in millimeters
        PageWidth = 122, // it's in millimeters
        PageHeight = 44
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);

string url = urlHelper.Action("Index", new { name = "value" });

return new UrlAsPdf("http://www.github.com")
{
    FileName = "TestExternalUrl.pdf",
    PageMargins = new Margins(3, 3, 3, 3)
};
```